# DiscordJS: Check if input is in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, discord.js

**Hello!**
I will try to do my best as possible to explain this issue i have.

**A bin with some of the code mentioned, with comments:**

[Codebin](https://codepen.io/menix/pen/zYrLBoq)

I am currently working on a Discord bot, where there is data stored in a .json file (As string).

- Maybe this should be converted to an array instead?

A user writes a command and the bot initializes a sequence where it will go through several options depending on whats found in the string.

I've been struggling with this far too long (atleast 10 hours now & i am severely out of ideas now) on getting a check in for user response, to see if the input he does is in the array.

**If i write !color 76561197458345 - it starts the process as seen below:**

[image: Text]

**As you see the Available Options for found Dino (Carnotaurus) is:**
[Utah1, Utah2]

Which is correct since its listed as the detailcrest options for Carnotaurus below in my json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Acrocanthosaurus",
    "detailcrest": "[Utah1, Utah2]",
    "underbelly": "[Utah3, Utah4]",
    "body1": "[Utah5, Utah6]",
    "body2": "[Utah7, Utah8]",
    "body3": "[Utah9, Utah10]"
  },
  {
    "name": "Carnotaurus",
    "detailcrest": "[Utah1, Utah2]",
    "underbelly": "[Utah3, Utah4]",
    "body1": "[Utah5, Utah6]",
    "body2": "[Utah7, Utah8]",
    "body3": "[Utah9, Utah10]"
  }
]
```

What then happens is that the user is gonna give a input based on the options found (This case Utah1, Utah2).

I want the bot to check the response from user in chat, if his answer is existing in the json file.

If respond to the bot in chat with Utah1 - it would proceed to next question (Because it exists).
If respond to the bot in chat with Pizza2 - it would respond (Not found, please select available options)

**TL;DR:**
I simply need a way to check if user response (word) is existing in the string
If Yes: continue, If No: error

I hope someone can give tips, or atleast push in the right direction on how to procceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple, but obviously not the most smart answer to my own solution - however it works as expected.

I've changed my .json strings to simply not include any brackets

```
"detailcrest": "Utah1, Utah2",
```

To search through my string i applied a .split() function (to seperate words with ,)

```
const inputCheck = color.detailcrest.toLowerCase().split(',').includes(detailcrest);
```

If i then do a if else statement on it, it returns true or false - for the given input, if it exists in the json file.

```
if (inputCheck === true) {
console.log("found")
} else {
console.log("False")
}
```

Obviously this wouldn't be the smartest way to proceed in a professional

But in my little bot it should work out with what is expected.

- Due to limits, i will accept my own answer as solution in two days.